# Returning results from array that contains two types of results

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

Hello I'm trying to retrun array type named `ZverejnenyUcetType` but the issue is that this array might contain two types : `StandartniUcetType` and `NestandardniUcetType`.

So the issue is when I try to return the array like this:

```
  string[] dic_vstup = new string[] { (line) };
            RozhraniWSDL.InformaceOPlatciType[] dic_vystup;
            RozhraniWSDL.rozhraniCRPDPH srv = new RozhraniWSDL.rozhraniCRPDPH();
            StatusType status = srv.getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce(dic_vstup, out dic_vystup);
            string abc = status.bezVypisuUctu.ToString();   // If it is already a string, then ToString not needed


            for (int i = 0; i < dic_vystup.Length; i++)
            {
                RozhraniWSDL.InformaceOPlatciType info = dic_vystup[i];


for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
{   
    file2.WriteLine((((RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType)(info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item)).cislo) + "-"

        + (((RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType)(info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item)).cislo) + "/" 

        + (((RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType)(info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item)).kodBanky));     
}}
```

I get following exception: unable to cast object of type `RozhraniWSDL.NestandardniUcetType` to type `RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType`.

`NestandardniUcetType` contains only one item - `cislo`

`StandartníUcetType` have 3 items- `predcislo`, `cislo`, `kod banky`

Here is an image of the array:

[image]

I thought that the solution might be to determinate which of the result are of type `StandartniUcetType` and which are `NestandardniUcetType`.

I would like to ask if this is possible to do?

I found this solution more common.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Post (an outline) of the 2 types and the array declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array has two different types, you could add an `if` statement, like this:

```
if (info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item is RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

A slightly better approach would be to cast using the `as` operator, like this:

```
RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType std = info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item as RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType;
if (std != null) {
    ...
}
RozhraniWSDL.NestandardniUcetType nstd = info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item as RozhraniWSDL.NestandardniUcetType;
if (nstd != null) {
    ...
}
```

Finally, a very good approach would be writing two separate methods for the two types, and using `dynamic` to perform a dispatch. To do that, define two functions, like this:

```
static void WriteToFile(RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType std, StreamWriter file) {
    ...
}
static void WriteToFile(RozhraniWSDL.NestandardniUcetType nstd, StreamWriter file) {
    ...
}
```

Now change your loop as follows:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
    dynamic item = info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item;
    WriteToFile(item, file2); // <<== Magic
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed by your knowledge. This helped me alot, thanks. May I ask if there is way to determinate how many items the array contains? I need to change x <= ItemsInArray. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

Using the OfType extension method over the array will filter for the type you need

```
foreach (var item in info.zverejneneUcty.OfType<RozhraniWSDL.StandardniUcetType>())
{
  file2.WriteLine(item.predcislo + "-" + item.cislo + "-" + item.kodBanky);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd redesign the types and remove the issue instead, through an abstract class, like this:

```
// I'm making up the inner types, adapt this to your code
public abstract class UcetType
{
    public virtual object predcislo { get; set; }
    public virtual object cislo { get; set; }
    public virtual object kodBanky { get; set; }

    public virtual void WriteToFile(StreamWriter file) 
    { 
        // build the string and write it to the file
        // considering all properties
        // this acts as "default" for this type and all derived ones
    }
}

public class StandardniUcetType : UcetType
{
    // This will use the abstract as-is
    // with all 3 properties and the "default" WriteToFile() method
}

public class NestandardniUcetType : UcetType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempting to use this will throw an exception
    /// </summary>
    public override object predcislo
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempting to use this will throw an exception
    /// </summary>
    public override object kodBanky
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    // change the way WriteToFile behaves
    public override void WriteToFile(StreamWriter file)
    {
        // build the string and write it to the file
        // only considering 'cislo' property
    }
}

// Usage example, based on question
for (int i = 0; i < dic_vystup.Length; i++)
{
    RozhraniWSDL.InformaceOPlatciType info = dic_vystup[i];   

    // I assume "3" is the expected length of the array ? Change the for like this:
    for (int x = 0; x <= info.zverejneneUcty.Length; x++)
    {   
        //Delegate to the WriteToFile() method the task to build and write the line!
        info.zverejneneUcty[x].Item.WriteToFile(file2);
    }
}
```

I see no benefit in a `dynamic` approach here. This is more readable and easy to expand in the future (need a new type ? just derive `UcetType` in a new class and override away).